# how to update key name of JSON in c#?

Tags: c#, json

Is there a way to update JSON key name or Change the existing Keyname of a json?

```
class NewBands
{
    private List<NSongs> _NBandName;

    public string NewBandName { get; set; }
    public List<NSongs> NBandName
    {
        get { return _NBandName; }
        set { _NBandName = value; }
    }
}


class NSongs
{
    public string NSongTitle { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Bands()
{
    dbBandsEntities dbband = new dbBandsEntities();

    var returnjson = dbband.Bands.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new NewBands()
    {
        NewBandName = x.BandName.ToString(),
        NBandName = dbband.BandSongs.AsEnumerable().Where(y => y.BandId == x.Id).Select(z => new NSongs() {
            NSongTitle = z.SongTitle
        }).ToList()
    });

    return Json(returnjson, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Output:

> [   {
>       "NewBandName": "Amber Pacific",
>       "NBandName": [
>         { "NSongTitle": "Fall Back Into My Arms" },
>         { "NSongTitle": "If I Fall" },
>         { "NSongTitle": "When I Found You" }
>       ]   },   {
>       "NewBandName": "Mayday Parade",
>       "NBandName": [
>         { "NSongTitle": "Misserable at Beast" },
>         { "NSongTitle": "The Problem with Big Picture is I can't see" }
>       ]   },   {
>       "NewBandName": "Fm Static",
>       "NBandName": [
>         { "NSongTitle": "Dear God" },
>         { "NSongTitle": "Her Father Songs" },
>         { "NSongTitle": "Last Train Home" },
>         { "NSongTitle": "Tonight" },
>         { "NSongTitle": "Black Tattoo" }
>       ]   }

I Want to update NBandName to BandName Itself.

Output should be:
{
    "NewBandName": "Amber Pacific",
    "Amber Pacific": [
      { "NSongTitle": "Fall Back Into My Arms" },
      { "NSongTitle": "If I Fall" },
      { "NSongTitle": "When I Found You" }
    ]
  }......

Comment: Since you assign `NBandName` the name will stay untouched. Modify the existing class or derive from the existing class and add a new property named `BandName` and assign the data to that property instead of `NBandName`

Comment: That seems like it would make it difficult to consume your data since each record will have a different key.

Comment: Yeah right, is there a chance that i can create it like/ or create it  this way { "NewBandName": "Amber Pacific", "Amber Pacific": [ { "NSongTitle": "Fall Back Into My Arms" }, { "NSongTitle": "If I Fall" }, { "NSongTitle": "When I Found You" } ] }...... or is there a way to change the keyname of "NBandName" to Real Band Name

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a list of `NewBands` objects you may create a list of dictionaries of string keys and object values. This allows to set arbitrary key names on the fly:

```
var returnjson = dbband.Bands.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    { "NewBandName", x.BandName.ToString() },
    { 
        x.BandName.ToString(), 
        dbband.BandSongs
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Where(y => y.BandId == x.Id)
            .Select(z => new NSongs() {
                NSongTitle = z.SongTitle
            })
            .ToList()
    }
});
```